# Is there a better way to write multiple OR statements in an if-statement?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

```
def get_string(no_of_times)
    1.upto(no_of_times) do 
    string_input = gets.chomp
    count_holes(string_input)
    end 
end

def count_holes(word)
    count = 0
    word.each_char do |char|
        if char == "A" || char == "D" || char == "O" || char == "P" || char == "Q" || char == "R" 
            count += 1
        elsif char == "B"
            count += 2
        end
    end
    $arr_of_holes << count
end



test_cases = gets.chomp.to_i

$arr_of_holes = []
get_string(test_cases)
puts $arr_of_holes
```

Hi all. I do not like the long condition in if statement while iterating over each character. So i wanted to ask you all if there is a better way to do this in ruby.

Thanks

Comment: and i will very thankful if you all could suggest any improvements in the code so the next time i can implement it
Thanks

Comment: Highly appreciate all your responses
thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
if %q{A D O P Q R}.include? char
    count += 1
elsif char == "B"
    count += 2
end
```

**Alternative** way using [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html):

```
def count_holes(word)
    holes = {
        'A' => 1,
        'D' => 1,
        'O' => 1,
        'P' => 1,
        'Q' => 1,
        'B' => 2,
    }
    count = word.chars.map { |char| holes.fetch(char, 0) }.inject :+
    $arr_of_holes << count
end
```

Comment: yeah it just came into my mind right now after i posted this :)
anyway thanks :)

Comment: And for single characters: `"ADOPQR".include? char` (although I would likely use the Array form)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with a case selection, as [multiple terms can be supplied to each `when`](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/):

```
case char
when "A", "D", "O", "P", "Q", "R"
  count += 1
when "B"
  count += 2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more compact than nacyot's answer:

```
count += case char
when "B" then 2
when "A", "D", "O".."R" then 1
else 0
end
```

The `else` line may not be required if there is not such case.

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
   word = "BROADLY"
   "ADOPQR".each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t + word.count(c) } + 2*word.count("B")
     #=> 6
```